# MongoDB obtain select field

Tags: python, mongodb

Currently in the process of creating a script with pymongo. I have a python script setup so whenever a user registers their account it stores the UserID and Account name in MongoDB.

At the moment I want to add a feature so whenever a user discontinues the service it sends a message which only contains their Account name.

I have this code:

```
y = patreons.find_one({"ID": ctx.message.author.id})
```

And it returns the following:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5dccf3c54d7b9081ad285a15'), 'ID': 203268468613709824, 'Github': 'Bencey2 '}
```

Any idea how I can get it so it only returns the Github Field?

Much appreciated

Bencey

Answer (score 0):

Specify the fields you need as you're trying to find a document. This should work:

```py
y = patreons.find_one({"ID": ctx.message.author.id}, {"Github": 1, "ID": 0, "_id": 0})
```